# Cannot get ubuntu installed UEFI

Tags: uefi

I've been at this all day. I'm running windows 7 and would like to install ubuntu but it just won't work. I turned off secure drive. I can boot the usb normally which gives me the whole "this boot is legacy..." whenever i try to use boot-repair and if i boot in uefi it just goes to windows instead. I used yumi to create the disk and tried creating it with the ubuntu disk write. I have no clue what i'm missing.

Comment: You have to boot with EFI enabled.

Comment: I recently conducted an experiment involving bootable external drives and an asus transformer tablet/netbook.  I inadvertently discovered that this computer will only boot 64 bit Ubuntu.  That may seem obvious to others with more experience with the newest hardware, but it came as a shock to me.  I don't suppose it is possible that you could have done something similar involving 32 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: EFI Was enabled. It was yumi that was creating the problem. Once I used a different utility it worked excellent with no need to use boot-repair. Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating your boot disk with `dd`, as in:

```
dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

Change `image.iso` to the filename you want to write and `/dev/sdc` to the device filename for your USB flash drive. Third-party disk-imaging tools might or might not create a disk image that's bootable in EFI mode. That said, some rare computers make it necessary to use such a third-party tool to prepare a bootable USB drive; but in these cases, you must ensure that the tool is capable of creating an EFI-bootable image. The last I checked, YUMI did *not* work for this. I don't know for sure about the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator. Tools that can create EFI-bootable disks often require explicitly setting an EFI compatibility option.

Once the image is created, you may need to use your firmware's built-in boot manager to boot it. This is usually accessed via a function key, but which one varies from one machine to another (and some use another key entirely, like Esc or Enter). If the drive is bootable in both BIOS/CSM/legacy and EFI/UEFI modes, there will normally be two entries for the disk in the boot manager. To boot in EFI/UEFI mode, select the entry that includes "UEFI" in the description. The one *without* "UEFI" in the description boots to BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

You can check your boot mode by looking for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`; if that directory is present, you've booted in EFI/UEFI mode. If it's absent, you've probably booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

Comment: I got it figured out. I think your way would have worked as well. I used win32diskimager (name?). I think yumi wasn't allowing it to boot 64x. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to figure this out, but I found something that works.  I have installed Ubuntu twice on my Toshiba Sattelite e45t-A4200 that was running windows 8.
Here's how:

1. Enter BIOS and change boot from UEFI to CSM (mine was under advanced),  change the boot priority to USB first and disable the Secure Boot.
2. Boot machine using the USB disk.
3. Install Ubuntu (in CSM mode) using the USB disk.  Don't bother "Download updates as you install" this time.
4. When you reboot your machine enter BIOS.If you computer has a HDD and SSD make the HDD the first.  Also, change your boot mode back to UEFI.
5. Reboot the machine using the USB drive.
6. Reinstall Ubuntu (in UEFI) using the USB disk.
7. Reboot the machine one last time from the USB drive.
8. Run boot-repair from the USB drive.

*Disclaimer*  I used this method to REPLACE windows.  I do not know that it would work with a side by side install.  For that, I know it works.

I hope this helps!

-Josh

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do a fresh install and had to re-figure this out.  My previous solution did not work.  Here are some things that I figured out about UEFI installation that made it work (properly).

I used a usb stick to boot with.  To boot in UEFI the boot stick must be formatted in FAT32 to boot.

For whatever reason, in my BIOS I had to "restore to defaults" for the boot stick to work.

After the installation was done I had to boot form the USB stick again and run "boot-repair" to make the installation work.  No problems since.  I hope this helps and I think it is a much better/easier way of installing using UEFI.